# There is no global variables in elixir. How to take variable from one function and use it in another?

Tags: scope, global-variables, elixir

I have a boardgame I have to make using elixir. The first function is called readFrom(aString) which will take a string and then extract the variables from it.
I don't want to bore you with the 20 variables within the readFrom function that I wrote, so I'll just make it simple for the sake of the question.

```
defmodule SnakesAndLadders do

def readFrom(aString) do
x=aString
end

def print() do
IO.inspect x
end 
end
```

So I just need to know a workaround to get variable x and use it into the function print(). Is there any possible way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just pass that as an argument? `print(x)` in `readFrom` and `def print(x) do ... end`.

Comment: Oh because the actual argument passed would be
"board 3 4
players 2
dice 1 2 2 2 2
ladder 5 11
snake 8 4
powerup escalator 6 9
powerup antivenom 7
powerup double 4
turns 10"
And then i have to extract each value into a variable so for example, board 3 4 means row=3 and column=4, and so readFrom is going to extract the argument into different variables.

Comment: Instead of using global variables, consider to use map and it will hold all of your arguments or use Task to return you these numbers, from other functions. Don't try to use OOP mindset in Elixir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the example code you posted:

```
defmodule SnakesAndLadders do

   def readFrom(aString) do
      x=aString
      print(x)
   end

   def print(s) do
      IO.inspect s
   end 
end
```

This would be the simplest way to accomplish this.  Don't rely on global variables--pass values to functions.

And given your comment, you'd probably want to do something like this in the readFrom function:

```
def readFrom("board " <> row column <> rest = aString) do
   {row,column}
end
```

That assumes that aString starts with `"board "`. But the concept of decomposing a string via pattern matching is a lot to get into so I'll leave that up to you to research further.

Comment: Yep this way is the best way. I've extracted each number from aString to their respective variables, and now I need to create and output the board.
https://gyazo.com/18dbd79d68fae93556bdece2b97c0b92?token=5f0d18f018be5107aaa3da00d4a359b1
I did this on java using a a lot of nested for loops, and while loops but they don't exist in elixir. Any tips?